# React - using state value only one time

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner on React, and I am confused on how to achieve this

I have a simple function which returns a component

```
renderCustomButtonText(style) {
    return (
    <span> 
     <input 
      value={this.state.contact}
      placeholder="Custom Button Text"
      />
    </span>
    );
  }
```

The input value is received from the state. When loading the page for the first time it gets this value from the database so that is okay, but when updating the state again, it gets changed again.

So, basically,  I want to store `{this.state.contact}` somewhere so that I can get the initial value of it. And NOT getting the updated store value, only the initial value which was loaded the first time.

I don't want to use Redux for such a simple use case. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try using `shouldComponentUpdate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use state with functional components you need class-based component, with functional components you are limited to render props.

When you need to interact with state, or component lifecycle hooks you need to use class-based components.

Comment: Well, I am already using it. Maybe you got confused, this function IS inside a component and is rendered by {this.renderCustomButtonText} inside the render()

Comment: Nope, I think you are confused, class-based components require ```class``` in its definition

Answer (score 0):

React updates its component whenever you use this.setState.
If you don't want to re-render your component, I would recommend setting the information to the `this`-instance instead of `this.state`.

e.g.

```
this.contact = contact;
```

However, since you're using the value prop of input, you need to update it each time the user inputs. What you could do is setting the state in the `componentWillMount` method with setState.

```
this.setState({ contact: '...' });
```

Then also update the state when the user inputs by adding a onInput event to the input component.

```
<input
  value={this.state.contact}
  onInput={e => this.setState({ contact: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Comment: This sort of works, butI cannot change the input value

Comment: But this updates the contact value each time a new value is entered, while I want to only store the initial state contact value

Comment: Define 'store'? You're only setting the innerState of the component. I see no harm in that.

Comment: I mean when I update the state the input value gets changed right? I don't want that. When the page is initially loaded, there is a 'contact' state value, I want to preserve or store that